# PDF readers for presenting Math online

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-software

In the current situation it seems especially important to be able to present your mathematical results online in a way that your audience does not fall asleep in front of their screens. But I am struggling to find suitable software one could use to enhance the usual beamer LaTeX presentations with some handwriting/drawing.

So I am searching for the following features:

- Allows to present PDFs, as generated by the beamer Latex package
- Compatibility with usual video conference software (should be easy, just share your screen)
- Easy to use and easy to access handwriting tools (pen, colors, laserpointer, etc.)
- Drawing should stay on the slide you drew them on, so you can go back to them and save them after your talk
- Program and Toolbar should not be visible to the audience (so maybe campatibility with 2 screens would be necessary here)
- Additionally: Shows next slide, time, additional notes, ... (only for the speaker)

What is the best tool you know for this purpose?

PS: I am not restricted to any operating system.

Comment: you could use Microsoft OneNote: it shows pages on which you can write with a tablet, and you can include pdf's or other images on each page; you can hide the toolbar if you wish.

Comment: But the toolbar will then also not be visible to myself, right?

Comment: Note that in Zoom for instance you can easily share a portion of the screen (Share Screen > Advanced > Portion of Screen), in which case visibility of the toolbar is not an issue. In that case Xournal++ works well for handwriting on pdfs.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that while I can present a beamer slide while looking at the camera, writing on a tablet requires looking down at it -- giving viewers an extended look at my shiny bald head... (For lectures, I usually disable the camera for this reason, among others -- students should focus on the material and not on me. But this is not as reasonable for a talk.)

Comment: @ChristianClason For a seminar, maybe. But for a full course I think that it is psychologically useful to be able to see your lecturer's face. But then again I am Italian, everyone knows we speak with our hands. :p

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The point is exactly that they won't be seeing my _face_ :) But, yes, some face-to-face at the beginning or end of the lecture (or during a break) is very useful. (Ideal would be some sort of hot-button switching similar to "hold space for unmute", but I haven't seen that anywhere -- camera and screen sharing takes too long to spool up each time.)

Comment: Personally, I find paper and pen best. It's much easier than entering them as *latex*. Until digital paper improves its recognition of mathematical hand-writing, I wouldn't bother. It's possible to spend much more time on presentation, rather than the thing we're all interested in - mathematics. This reminds me of something Atiyah said about mathematics: he liked collaboration, but he noted that serious thinking still requires concentration on one's own.

Comment: @Christian: with [OBS](https://obsproject.com) (“Open Broadcaster Software”) you can put together a setup that allows quick switching between slides, your live video, and combinations (e.g. slides with the video inset in a corner).  The interface is good, and the learning curve is much gentler than you might expect.

Comment: @Peter and then you share the OBS window on BBB rather than the camera?

Comment: I know two approaches: (1) screen-share a suitably set-up OBS window; (2) use OBS to stream to a “virtual camera”, and then in Zoom (or Teams or whatever equivalent you’re using) select that virtual camera as your video feed.  They seem to each have slight tradeoffs in terms of interface, responsiveness, and video quality.  I‘m not at all an expert, though — I’ve only recently started using it — so if you google around you can find a lot more informed discussion of the options!

Answer (score 9):

For a couple of talks I borrowed an iPad and used the app Notability, which seems to cover most of what you wanted.

- I presented a PDF prepared with Beamer.
- The talk was through Zoom, which allows you to share an iPad screen connected through Airplay (or through a cable in theory, but I could not get this to work).
- I wrote with an Apple pencil and was happy with the options for different colours, styles etc that Notability provides, and the ease of accessing them during the talk. (Perhaps relevant here is to re-emphasize that this was borrowed equipment: I obviously practiced with it a little in advance, but not for so long, so this is some evidence that the learning curve is not steep).
- Notability is a note-taking app, and this process worked exactly as it would for annotating a PDF file, so annotations remain on the slide indefinitely once written. (In fact one feature that might have been helpful would be an easy way to clear all the annotations! I just imported the PDF again to a new Notability document.)
- Only the slides were visible to the audience, not the controls. (To clarify, by way of comparison with other answers: the controls were always visible to me.)
- I could not see things like the next slide or private notes, but I did not try to set this up, so maybe it is possible. I think I could probably see the time, but I am not 100% sure now.

As an audience member, I must say I have much preferred when speakers have not used Beamer, but written at least most things in real time like a board talk, although the lack of space and slow pace of writing with a stylus does make this rather difficult. (I did not even do it myself, despite this preference -- I had too many figures, and no previous experience using the stylus or the software, which put me off.) If you do this I think a feature to look for is the ability for the audience to see both the page you are writing on and the previous one, e.g. as two portrait pages side by side. I think Xournal can do this (and is especially on topic here because symplectic geometer Denis Auroux has some role in its development).

Comment: Thanks for sharing you experience! I agree that using just beamer slides is kind of tiring for the audience. That's why I would like to have a way to e.g. add handwritten proofs etc. during the talk to a Latex written Theorem.

Comment: Could you share some details on the second point? How does Zoom connect via Airplay? (I have pretty much the same setup for my lectures, except that I use GoodNotes instead of Notability -- which allows setting a blackboard-looking page background -- and BigBlueButton; I need a separate program for mirroring the iPad to my desktop which I then share.)

Comment: Have a look at the following link for zoom / Apple screen sharing: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204726885-Screen-Share-Using-Airplay-Mirroring

Comment: But that's for Zoom Room, which requires special hardware, right? It's not included in the Zoom software client? Or can you use it with just a PC?

Comment: One drawback I found in Notability is that it cannot switch the pages in the slides instantly. Sometimes you present each new line in the slide one by one by using the command \pause in latex. In Acrobat Reader you can change pages instantly

Comment: Apologies, I had intended to share this link: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201379235

Comment: @asahay Indeed, I just tested this, and Zoom (now) includes an AirPlay client so you can mirror your iPad without additional software. Thank you! I learned something new today :) (Too bad I have  to -- and want to! -- use BigBlueButton for teaching. But this will be quite helpful for the next seminar talk I give!)

Comment: @PaataIvanishvili Do you mean switching slides without a page transition? (For example, that the previous slide is dragged to the left to reveal the new one underneath.)  I was also bothered by this, but found that while this transition was displayed on the tablet, on the screen share there was no transition -- possibly just because the refresh rate was not high enough!

Comment: @MatthewPressland, yes, switching slides without a page transition. Today I submitted a request to Notability support team to add this feature. Thanks for letting me know that this page transition is not seen for participants of the zoom meeting due to low refresh rate.

Comment: @PaataIvanishvili I'm not totally sure that was the reason (for one talk I ended up using a different tablet and different app, and then the page transition was visible -- the other parts of the setup were the same). It just seems like a possibility, because it is weird behaviour if intended.

Comment: @MatthewPressland, yesterday I played with it a little bit and I guess I figured it out how to switch slides without page transition. Join a zoom meeting on your computer. Click "Share screen", Choose "iPone/iPad via AirPlay". Next, choose "Screen Mirroring" on your iPad, and open Notability app. Open any notes, click "3 dots" on the top right corner, click "view", choose "Single Page", and that is it. People in zoom will not see your page transition (only you will see page transition on your iPad).

Answer (score 7):

### [XODO PDF READER](https://www.xodo.com/)

Free to use. For the Windows version:

> Allows to present PDFs, as generated by the beamer Latex package

Yes

> Compatibility with usual video conference software (should be easy, just share your screen)

Yes

> Easy to use and easy to access handwriting tools (pen, colors, laserpointer, etc.)

It is easy to write in a single color; it takes a few clicks to change it because the toolbar is not on the screen (as per your other request). I normally highlight the cursor with a button on my pen

> Drawing should stay on the slide you drew them on, so you can go back to them and save them after your talk

Yes

> Program and Toolbar should not be visible to the audience (so maybe campatibility with 2 screens would be necessary here)

Only the slides are visible. Tapping on the touchscreen shows a toolbar (pen and finger touches do different things; for instance you can move to the next slide with a flicker). I don't have a second screen on my tablet so I don't know if it supports it.

> Additionally: Shows next slide, time, additional notes, ... (only for the speaker)

No.

Answer (score 4):

If your presentation is based on a Beamer file, I recommend [PdfPc](https://pdfpc.github.io/). It supports a hidden dashboard for the speaker, showing previous/next slides and some annotation and pointing tools.

Moreover, it allows you to jump among sections without having to run slide by slide - which is particularly cumbersome when a single frame corresponds to multiple pages on the pdf file.

In practice, when using PdfPc you then would only share the presentation window (but not the speaker dashboard) on your video conferencing software.